# Remix: Warning: Extra attributes from the server: class

Tags: remix.run

I am using remix and just created the most basic project by running `npx create-remix@latest`. Right out the gate, I get this in my console when running `npm run dev`.

```
Warning: Extra attributes from the server: class
```

It goes away after removing the `<Scripts />` tag, but I think I need that?

Answer (score 6):

That's a React error, it happens when you're hydration a server-side rendered HTML but the HTML doesn't match what React expected it to be when hydrating.

The most common reason for this to happen is when a browser extension is changing the HTML before React hydration process run.

Removing the Scripts components hide the error because you're not hydrating React client-side anymore.

Comment: Ok but how do you handle that?

Comment: If the culprit is a browser extension, then you need to wait for when React itself fix the issue (https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24430), another option is to apply something like Remix islands (https://github.com/Xiphe/remix-island) to don't let Remix render the whole document